# Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined setting up node/express server and webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm trying to set up a very simple script that fetch's data from an API and consumes it's data. I need to use CORS, so I set up a node/express server and pointed it to my Webpack bundle. The error I am getting is `global is not defined`. From googling this I've seen people fix their problems by disabling react/redux tools which seemed to point at hot reloading. Problem is, I'm not using hot reloading.

After seeing that I looked into what I am using global which pointed at my fetch expression. However, removing all my fetch code didn't solve anything

My server looks like this

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server running on http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
});
```

and my webpack config looks like this

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './scripts/app.js'],
    target: "node",
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: './dist/bundle.js' },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015'],
                    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

All i can think of now is that I didn't set up my express server correctly or I'm missing something in my webpack config.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious.  Have a stack trace?

Comment: `at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9fdd931…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap 9fdd931…:39)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9fdd931…:19)
    at bootstrap 9fdd931…:39
    at bootstrap 9fdd931…:39`

Comment: Damn, just tried to turn off EVERY extension I had and no dice

Comment: Something do with my polyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, The issue was being caused by placing babel-polyfill in my entry point in my webpack.config. As I already had a preset for ES2015 I didn't need the polyfill.

I am unsure as to why I had placed the babel-polyfill in my entry.